# Could not find a version that satisfies the requierement for installing tensorflow via pip

Tags: pip

```
C:\Users\Recep>py -m  pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I looked up in the net learned that this error happens when your out of some packages thats important but when i looked up in the tensorflows website looks like i have all the packages thats needed.thank you in advance.

Comment: Run `py -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_platform())"`, what does it output?

Comment: I didnt try it yet cuz im on mobile right now but i think i found the problem.  I guess python 3.7.4 that i use isnt supported by tensorflow

Comment: Yes, this will be the main issue, have to wait until [#20517](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517) is solved and a new version is released.

Comment: yes it turns out that it was really the problem but i installed 3.6 version and its now working normally thank you guys for your helps.